# Как записать в файл несколько строк?

Tags: php

Не могу найти в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.filesystem.php) какая именно функция записывает в файл несколько строк. Все функции записывают строку в файл.

Допустим, у меня есть строка:

```
'define("EXAMPLE", "File Write"; define("EXAMPLE1", "File Write1"; define("EXAMPLE2", "File Write2";'
```

Как её записать в *file.php* с помощью *PHP*?

Вопрос снят, спасибо [Regent](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/183458/regent).

Comment: открыть notepad, копи-пастнуть (скобки только закройте) и сохранить как file.php

Comment: Я спрашиваю, как это сделать через PHP файл

Comment: Вы хотите в php файле создавать php файлы?

Comment: С помощью PHP, верно. Разные CMS умеют же создавать конфиги и прочее. Как они это делают?

Comment: Чтобы записать в файл что угодно, достаточно функции, умеющей писать по 1 байту. У вас есть функция, которая может записать цЕлую строку. Уже почти роскошь. А с помощью цикла и этой функции можно записать какое угодно количество строк.

Comment: Тоесть \n добавлять? Или как? Если можно, готовый пример.

Comment: Можно `"\r\n"` (или `"\n"`, в зависимости от вашей ОС). Либо использовать спец. константу для этого (`PHP_EOL`). `fwrite($fileHandler, "text" . PHP_EOL);`, например.

Comment: ура! Заработало, большое вам спасибо! Сделал так:
`<?
$fileHandler = fopen('config.php', 'w');
$text = 'define("EXAMPLE", "File Write";
define("EXAMPLE1", "File Write1";
define("EXAMPLE2", "File Write2";';
$write = fwrite($fileHandler, $text . PHP_EOL);
?>`

Comment: @Андрей оформите свое решение как ответ. тогда можно будет "закрыть" Ваш вопрос

Comment: А как это сделать? Я свой ответ не могу ответить как решение и в комментариях тоже

Comment: Зайдите в вопрос и нажмите "Ответить на собственный вопрос" - синяя кнопка внизу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос снят, спасибо за помощь @Regent.

Сделал так:

```
<?
    $fileHandler = fopen('config.php', 'w');
    $text = 'define("EXAMPLE", "File Write";define("EXAMPLE1", "File Write1";define("EXAMPLE2", "File Write2";';
    $write = fwrite($fileHandler, $text . PHP_EOL);
?>
```

Comment: На здоровье. Нужно было в ответ код добавить - тогда бы ваш ответ не попал под критику.